# getting distinct values from array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, underscore.js, lodash

My data is in the following format..

```
    var data= [['typeName', 'valueName'], ['type1', 'value1'],
['type1', 'value2'],['type2', 'value3'],['type2', 'value4']]
```

I wish to transform the above data to data as below..

```
    var resultdata=[{'typeName':'type1','valueName':['value1','value2']},
{'typeName':'type2','valueName':['value3','value4']}]
```

Basically I pick up distinct 'typeName' values and then group 'valueName' values by 'typeName' values.

I would preferably use only knockoutjs, lodash or underscorejs as my soln already uses them but I'm open to other solutions as well..

All help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what is the criteria to create result data from your structure.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution using underscore should do the trick:

```
var result= _.chain(data)
    .rest()
    .groupBy( value => value[0])
    .map( (value,key) => ({ [data[0][0]]: key, [data[0][1]]: _.map(value, val => val[1])}))
    .value();
```

This solution uses [**rest**](http://underscorejs.org/#rest) to skip the first item in the data array (the type descriptors). The array is then [**grouped**](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) by the first value in the array (the type) and the mapping returns the grouping in the required form using es6 [**object initializer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) notation.

Comment: If I change the data to [['typeName', 'valueName','extraName'], 
['type1', 'value1','extra1'],
['type1', 'value2','extra2'],['type2', 'value3','extra3'],['type2', 'value4','extra4']], the valuename has extraname values, Is it viable to ensure that valuename always has the second field values. Also, is it possible to not hardcode typename and valuename in map..

Comment: Tweaked the code to use the strings from the first data item as the property names of the result and also to use the second value

Comment: Impressive solution!  I'd recommend some comments since the code is not very easy to understand when reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Given the result as:

```
var resultdata=[
    {'typeName':'type1'},{'valueName':['value1','value2']},
    {'typeName':'type2'},{'valueName':['value3','value4']}
]
```

I'm going to call 'typeName' the category and 'valueName' the items.

Since the original data look like this:

```
var data= [
    ['typeName', 'valueName'], 
    ['type1', 'value1'],
    ['type1', 'value2'],
    ['type2', 'value3'],
    ['type2', 'value4']
]
```

It is clear there is a pattern.  The first row of data is what we'll use as labels for category and items.  All the remaining data represent the values being used inside category and items.

The first step is to extract the labels:

```
 var categoryLabel = data[0][0];
 var itemLabel = data[0][1];
```

Next, the unique categories will need to be determined, so we'll use reduce to build an array of unique categories:

```
 var categories = data
     .filter(function(row, i) { return i > 0 }) // remove the labels
     .reduce(function(arrCategories, currRow) {
         // Add the current rows' category if it doesn't already exist
         var currCategory = currRow[0];
         if (arrCategories.indexOf(currCategory) === -1) {
           return arrCategories.concat(currCategory);
         }
         return arrCategories;
     }, [])
```

Now that you have a set of categories, you just need to iterate over each one to find all items that belong to it:

```
 var valuesByCategory = {};
 categories.forEach(function(category) {
   // find all the data items that match the category
   var items = data
     .filter(function(row) { return row[0] === category; })
     .reduce(function(arrItems, currRow) {
       var currItem = currRow[1];
       if (arrItems.indexOf(currItem) === -1) {
          return arrItems.concat(currItem);
       }
       return arrItems;
     }, []);
   valuesByCategory[category] = items;
 });
```

Now that all the data has been parsed out, the only thing left to do is build the resultant array:

```
 var resultdata = [];
 // iterate through each of the categories
 categories.forEach(function(category) {
   // using the category label, output an object with the label and category
   var categoryObj = {};
   categoryObj[categoryLabel] = category;
   resultdata.push(categoryObj);


   // Next, create a items object containing all the values
   var itemsObj = {};
   itemsObj[itemLabel] = valuesByCategory[category];
   resultdata.push(itemsObj);
 }
```

and that's it :)

The best part is that you don't need any external libraries.  This is all ES2015 javascript!

Comment: Sincerely appreciate your help specially the explanations and you have given an answer which matched my question when i put it first and result data structure was [
    {'typeName':'type1'},{'valueName':['value1','value2']},
    {'typeName':'type2'},{'valueName':['value3','value4']}
], but later i updated the structure to [{'typeName':'type1','valueName':['value1','value2']},
{'typeName':'type2','valueName':['value3','value4']}], I'm sure you started before mychanges, would appreciate if you changed your answer

Comment: I would but you've already selected an answer, so there is no point :)

Comment: ok, got it.. var categoryObj = {};
   categoryObj[categoryLabel] = category;
   categoryObj[itemLabel] = valuesByCategory[category];
   resultdata.push(categoryObj);

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lodash version of Gruff Bunnies solution:

```
var data= [['typeName', 'valueName'], ['type1', 'value1'], ['type1', 'value2'],['type2', 'value3'],['type2', 'value4']]
var names = data[0]
var values = _.tail(data)

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  _(values)
    .groupBy(0)
    .map( (value, key) => ({ [names[0]]: key, [names[1]]: _.map(value, 1)}) )
    .value()
))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nmf1fdf5/